Can I mount a hoist to the garage ceiling joists?
I want to install a hoist in my garage to load a large generator into my truck. It is a 880 lb. lift capable hoist, but I doubt I'll ever lift more than 350 lbs.
I have the hardware to mount the hoist (12 ga. unistrut;  six 500 lb. rated L brackets; 1/2 " bolts; two 700 lb. trollies for mounting the hoist to the unistrut). My ceiling joists are 2"x8" set on 19-inch centers and span approx. 24 ft. The unistrut is 4 ft. long and will span and connect to three of the ceiling joists approx. 12 ft. from the nearest wall.
I've paused the project to consider whether the ceiling joists are capable of handling 350 lbs. suspended by a hoist. Thoughts? If the answer is no, how would I reinforce the ceiling joists to have confidence in the end project?

If you balance it across 3 that's less than 150lb on each one.   If you are the only user and you use it as planned that is.  Static load, slow careful lift, no human factors.  With solid joists I wouldn't even think to ask at 150lb.

Not being an engineer, I just wanted some thoughts/feedback before investing time in installation. Thanks.

If the joists are exposed and run across the width of the truck bed you could use temporary "crutches" to add support to the appropriate joists a little more than a truck-width apart.  That would reduce the effective span from 24' to closer to 8' to 10'.  If they can be hinged from framing under the three joists then it might be more convenient to deploy them when needed.

If loading the generator is the only reason to have a hoist, I should mention that a hand cranked pickup truck bed crane is less expensive, doesn't need wiring or roof structural evaluation and goes with you to your destination to offload the cargo.

@MTA that's a very good idea, although it is not cheaper.  The cheapest truck crane may be cheaper than  some better garage hoists but you can use a block and tackle hung from a 2x4 across a few joists and the whole project stays under $30 including hardware and beer.

@RiverRat I'm not an engineer either and your are good to be asking.  I'm just saying that if a solid 8 inch joist can't support 150 lb anywhere along its length I'd be afraid to stand under it let alone lift anything with it.   According to The Sagulator you'll have an acceptable 1/8 inch sag if you do this smack in the middle.  This depends of course on what else the joists are doing.   Are they just tying the walls?  Is there a room above?  Is there a hot tub in the middle of that room?

unistrut might be too flexible and put all the load on the center joist. but I guess you can loosen the bolts on the center bracket a bit to compensate.

I assume you're talking about something like this Harbor Freight hoist? https://www.harborfreight.com/880-lb-electric-hoist-with-remote-control-62854.html  Do you have access to the tops of the joists, or is there a floor there?

For me to have confidence in the end project, it'd be made out of steel I beams. That's what hoists attach to. Getting 350 pounds into a truck requires a 12 pack and three friends. How is it getting back out of the truck.....
